# Application get close while working on long running task in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, pdf, compression

F/crash_dump64(14834): crash_dump.cpp:494] failed to attach to thread 609: Permission denied

Application close automatically while working on long running task in android 13

Physical Device : Realme/Samsung

Technology: Flutter.

I am try to compress pdf file using PdfCompression library in flutter

Comment: try cold booting the emulator

Comment: How can I cold boot with real/physical device?
I using real/physical device as I mention.@editix

Comment: did you enable USB Debugging in your device ?

Comment: ask also for user permissions to grant storage access, and i think you may enable background tasks.